# Connect to localhost from iPhone - macOS Monterey

Tags: ios, localhost

Before updating to Mac OS Monterey I was able to connect to localhost and any port as long as I was on the same internal network. However this no longer seems to be working.

I have also tried to access via xxxx.local which only prints an html page that says "It Works!" which is located in `/Library/Documents/WebServer/index.html.en`. But if I navigate to any port, things just seem to just hangup.

Steps taken:

1. System Preference > Network > IP Address
2. Connect device to same network
3. Enter in ipaddress:port into browser

Get failed to connect message.

Suggestions?

Comment: Could you please describe your scenario step by step? It's unclear what you're trying to achieve and how. Consider reading the guide: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)